# foreach loop throwing an error

Tags: php, foreach, dreamweaver

I am passing an array into a php page from a js call(ajax) and its throwing an error . The line of code that the error is in is:

```
     foreach ($array as list($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g, $h)) {
```

It's my first attempt at pdo.

Can anyone see what is wrong with the code?

**js & ajax call:**

```
  var outerarray=[];
  var innerarray = [];
  innerarray[0]="1";
  innerarray[1]="2";
  innerarray[2]="3";
  innerarray[3]="4";
  innerarray[4]="5";
  innerarray[5]="6";    
  innerarray[6]="7";
  innerarray[7]="8";
  innerarray[8]="9";
  innerarray[9]="10";
  innerarray[10]="11";  
  innerarray[11]="1";                
  innerarray[12]="13";
  outerarray[0]=innerarray;     

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/upadateElements.php",        
    data: {outerarray:outerarray},          
    success:function(data){
      alert("data:"+data);                                      
    },
    error: function(data){
       alert("failure");
    }
  });
```

**updateElements.php code**

```
   $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8', username, password, array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));


  $array[]=$_POST['outerarray'];
  foreach ($array as list($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g, $h)) {
      $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE a=:a AND b=:b");
      $stmt->execute(array(':a' => $a, ':b' => $b));
      $row_count = $stmt->rowCount();   
      if($row_count==0){
         $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h) VALUES(:field1,:field2,:field3,:field4,:field5,:field6,:field7,:field8)");                          $stmt->execute(array(':field1' => $a, ':field2' => $b, ':field3' => $c, ':field4' => $d, ':field5' => $e, ':field6' => $f, ':field7' => $g, ':field8' => $h));
         $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();                    
       }

       if($affected_rows !=0){          
         echo "success";
       }else{
         echo "fail";
       }
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Does the code work? If so, who cares what the editor is saying ?

Comment: I cant run the code until I am sure its ok as it will screw up my db, dreamweaver has highlighted the line of code in red

Comment: Should it be `innerarray[11]="1";` or `innerarray[11]="12";`?

Comment: Dreamweaver is not always right.

Comment: @jonhopkins that value of the array is not relevant, I have stripped out the data and the db table name etc to simplify

Comment: ok I'll run the code and return with the result

Comment: foreach as list is a quite recent feature and what editors think of it may be not relevant.

Comment: @BarryWatts ok no problem. Just wasn't sure if it was a typo or even real data, and since you said the code directly affects your db, didn't want you to accidentally mess it up.

Comment: I have run the code but the php page is not returning any data and not updating the db

Comment: heres the error its throwing up PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_LIST in ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Edakos for helping me solve this. the problem is you cannot use list() in a foreach loop  in PHP<5.5

I have no idea why people would vote down this question.

Answer (score 0):

In your `SELECT` SQL statement you are searching the column `pagebref`, but in your `INSERT` statement you are trying to fill the column `b` with tha same value. Check your column names.

Also take care of using `list` inside a `foreach` only with PHP >= 5.5. For older versions, an alternative could be:

```
foreach ($array as $data) {
    list($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g, $h) = $data;
    ...
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo from stripping out the real data. the error I am getting is PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_LIST in /home/etc/etc............on line..

Comment: if I strip out everything inside the 'foreach' loop, the error is still highlighted in dreamweaver, its definitley the 'foreach' line that is the problem

Comment: I'm running php 5.3 on my server, is this the issue?

Comment: take care of using `list` inside a `foreach`, [it only works with PHP >= 5.5](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: thank you, I misread on php.net Unpacking nested arrays with list() 
'(PHP 5 >= 5.5.0)

PHP 5.5 added the ability to iterate over an array of arrays and unpack the nested array into loop variables by providing a list() as the value.'
I missed the PHP 5.5. bit, can you add as an answer so I can close this

Comment: just for completeness: the unpacking would probably not have worked if I understand the feature right, only `$a` and `$b` would have received values